# Execution context and closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I know how to implement closures but I have trouble understanding why closures happen. For example:

```
function foo(){
    var a = 4;
    return function innerFoo(){
        alert(a);
    };
};
var bar = foo();
bar();                   // alerts 4
```

I know what to expect when I see the code above, but when I try to follow it logically, it doesn't make sense. I think my understanding of execution context and its scope chain is wrong.

This is how I expect the program to run:

```
function foo(){
    var a = 4;
    return function innerFoo(){
        alert(a);
    };
};

var bar = foo(); // function foo() is executed, creating a foo execution context(EC)
                 // fooEC = {scopeChain: [fooEV.VO, globalEC.VO],
                 //                  VO: {innerFoo: pointer to innerFoo(),
                 //                              a: 4}};

                 // So, the pointer to innerFoo() is returned to bar
                 // fooEC is exited
bar(); // bar points to code in innerFoo(), creates a innerFoo execution context
       // innerFooEC = {scopeChain: [innerFoo.VO, globalEC.VO],
       //                       VO: { }};

       // interpreter searches innerFooEC.VO for variable "a", none found, looks
       // down the scope chain at the global variable object,
       // globalEC = {scopeChain: [globalEC.VO],
       //                     VO: {foo: pointer to foo(),
       //                          bar: pointer to innerFoo()}};  
       // a is undefined
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think the key here is to understand lexical scope in conjunction with closures.

Comment: `innerFooEC`'s `scopeChain` would be `[innerFooEC.VO].concat(fooEC.scopeChain);` or `[innerFooEC.VO, fooEC.VO, globalEC.VO]`

Comment: `bar` points to the `innerFoo` function object (not only its code), and that function object has a pointer to its parent environment: `fooEC`. Which will be used for the scope chain when the function is called - it's *not* the global object that follows `innerFoo.VO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in

```
bar points to code in innerFoo()
```

a closure is more than a pointer to code, it's a pointer to code **plus** an environment; that is the environment where `a` is defined.

When you execute a closure the scope chain is the one that was active **when the closure was defined** (i.e. inside `foo`), not the one where the call is made.

Note that a closure captures **variables**, not **values**. This can be observed with:

```
function getset(x) {
    var a = x;
    function getter() { return a; }
    function setter(x) { a = x; }
    return [getter, setter];
}

var gs1 = getset(12);
var gs2 = getset(34);

console.log(gs1[0]()); // --> 12
console.log(gs2[0]()); // --> 34
gs1[1](1122);
gs2[1](3344);
console.log(gs1[0]()); // --> 1122
console.log(gs2[0]()); // --> 3344
```

i.e. each pair of getter/setter will have its own variable shared between the two closures, but separate from the other pair.

This is the source of what is in my experience the most frequent mistake with closures created in a loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    node.textContent = "click me (" + i + ")";
    node.onclick = function() { alert(i); };
    document.body.appendChild(node);
}
```

In this code all the 10 elements, when clicked, will display **the same number** (10) because all of the closures are sharing the same `i` variable used in the loop and 10 is the final value the variable will have.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. So, if I understand correctly, when the closure is defined at the invocation of foo(), an instance of the scope chain is "saved" and linked as the parent scope chain to innerFoo()? So if i declare `var bar = foo(); var bar2 = foo(); bar(); bar2();` bar and bar2 are looking at two unique scope chains?

Comment: @Genos: exactly. Every time you call `foo` a new closure is created with its own independent `a` variable. Note that **variables** are captured, not values; this means that if you create **two** closures in the same scope capturing the same variable they are sharing it, i.e. if one changes the variable the other will see the change. See edit.